# Shodan Python API "count" problem with returned values with port facet

Tags: python, api, filter, shodan

i have a problem with Shodan "count" request, some code:

```
...

api=shodan.Shodan(API_KEY)
FACETS=[("port",361), . . .] #limit 361 values
api.count("port: x, y , ...",facets=FACETS) # filter for 361 port given

...
```

when i print the summary for the port facet, there are ports that i haven't required with their summarized values; moreover, several required ports are not displayed, however taking the ports individually, they are displayed with the respective quantity found

i missing something, or there are problem with the api?

Thx!